# Is there a way to Deserialize ProtectedTicket in AspNetUser Table?

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin

Based on what i know (correct me if i am wrong) the 'access_token' is equivalent to the 'protected ticket' field in AspNetUser table. It's just hashed.

What i am planning to do is deserialize the protected ticket to get the access_token value.

I am trying to support a SSO scenario wherein, the user can access multiple application using the same access token.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you are asking how to reverse a hash ('protected ticket') , to get the original value (access_token)?

Comment: @F.StephenQ yes you got that right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, if the hash function used is a cryptographic hash, which the circumstances suggest, this is definitionally impossible (or should be...). Cryptographic hash functions are designed to be extremely expensive (ideally impossible) to reverse, and so the most effective method you have would be to attempt to brute-force the hash, I.e. running inputs through the hash function until you get one that produces the output you want. Even then, there's no telling how long it would take you to find it. It is strongly recommended not to write anything that depends on routinely brute-forcing a cryptographic hash.

Of course, its possible that the possible inputs are incredibly small (I.e. at most 16 bits or so), or that the function used is not a cryptographic hash function (I.e. its something like base64 encoding or rot-13). In that case, you might have a method to reverse the "hash" efficiently.

However, I strongly suspect that is not the case. In this endeavour, I think you are simply out of luck, and will have to find another way to get the functionality you desire.

Comment: alright, thanks for that tip. I will have to go back to the drawing board :)

Comment: Hope you find a workaround! If you don't mind terribly, and agree that this the correct solution, could you mark this answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm a bit late, but it should be possible. The data of ProtectedTicket will be secured by Microsoft.Owin.Security.ISecureDataFormat.Protect. It's not a one way hash. So it can be reversed. You can look this up on Github in the Katana project (Microsoft's Owin implementation):

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security/DataHandler/SecureDataFormat.cs

As you can see, this interface provides a method Unprotect also. Didn't test it, but you could give it a shoot.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same token on the same apps as long the jwt token is signed with the same credentials (audience and secret) on every app. This allows every app to verify that the token is valid. this means, how-ever, that every app must know audience id and secret in the backend